# Print CSS issue in IE7 compatibility view

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing, intranet

I am developing a web page that will only be available from the company's intranet. At first the client's requirements was that if needed to work with IE8 which was fine.

Our first problem was that after launching the site live so the client can test it, we realized that every employee's IE was configured to open intranet's website in compatibility mode (The way employees computer are set up) which destroyed everything visually since nothing was tested for IE7...

I managed to make it work at 95% by including this meta tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

For the other small glitches on the page, I included a small script to detect if it was in compatibility mode and then load another css to fix those other glitches and it works perfectly, everything went back to the right place and the design is fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    try { JSON } catch (e) {
        var cssLink = $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/compatibilityMode.css'>");
        $("head").append(cssLink);
    }
});
```

The problem now is that they need to be able to print that page so I need to make a css for print. The page is divided in sections and before every one of them I use this code to do a page break. EX :

```
.part2 { page-break-before: always; }
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and IE9+ but in compatibility mode it's ignored and the print preview is completely messed up...

I researched a lot on the web and the page-break-before property is supposed to be supported since IE4 so I do not understand why it's not working...

Also, to tell IE which styles to apply to the print version, I put my print css inside this tag :

```
@media print { }
```

According to my research online, some people say that this is not supported in IE8- since it's media queries and some says it is supported because media types were supported way before media queries and it should work...

I really don't know what to try and where to look anymore, was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction or give me any suggestions as what to try next..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: someone ?....Please....lol

Comment: Well, I managed to fix the problem. Appending this :

https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv

 to the head in the script you see in my question fixed it!